# How To Get Response Of A Form Submit With Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm studying **JavaScript** (without **jQuery**) and I try to get the response of a **form submit**.

Here is a (little modified) sample form example given on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp);

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JavaScript FORMS Example #3</h1>
        <br>
        <h3>validating form</h3>
        <form
            name="myForm" action="http://www.w3schools.com/js/demo_form.asp"
            onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
        </form>
        <br>
        <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

            if(x == null || x =="") {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is to get the response of the submited form. The response can be a simple **text**, **XML** or **JSON** formatted. (Sure if the response is plain text, I can parse it with `JSON.parse()` method)

I have searched/sweeped SO but all the answers regarding to the "*getting response of the form submit*" or similiar questions using **jQuery**, however, I am searching for an exact **pure** **JavaScript** solution.

Edit: The focus of the question is **not** making an AJAX call without jQuery. I'm simply asking for a possible simple solution if there is any.

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`window.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (<- pay attention to browser compatibility)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: @Gerald Schneider : I don't think so, I'm not asking making an AJAX call without jQuery, the focus tag of the question is not AJAX but HTML forms.

Comment: what you want to do is the very definition of AJAX.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider : If so, are you saying that it is impossible to get the form submit response without AJAX. Can you also give some links?

Comment: The process of submitting a form without reloading the page is generally called AJAX. So I'd say yes, it is impossible to do so without it. The linked question shows how to do that with pure JavaScript.

Comment: The definition of Ajax is **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**. Ajax pretty much covers any call to a server from javascript, which submitting a form and getting a response is. You can get a form to submit without Javascript and just use whatever server side language you want to process it.